# Making com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1 work

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to migrate some code to use an `NSManagedObjectContext` with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`.

I'm sometimes getting very odd errors after saving the context to its parent, and then saving the parent. I'm wondering if these are due to be not using the `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` context correctly.

I've turned on [`-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1`](http://jeffreyearly.com/2014/08/06/note-on-core-data-concurrency/) to try to debug this. I'm pretty sure that this is not working however. If I perform operations on managed object context or change its objects without using `performBlock:`, I don't get an error or a throw.

Here's how I've set up the scheme's arguments:[image: Schema Edit]. I've also tried it without the leading `-`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does your console logs `CoreData: annotation: Core Data multi-threading assertions enabled.` at launch?

Comment: I recommend this reading btw : http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging/

Comment: @Bigood I don't see that if I search in the console log with either the `-` there, or not there. Dumb question – does it work with the simulator?

Comment: I guess so, but I didn't have a chance to try. Checks : do you target iOS 8? And do you edit the Run action of your scheme?

Comment: Hey, thanks both, and @Bigood – it states at that link that it's iOS 8 only! I was using the iOS 7 simulator. Switching to 8 and I see it in the console. Lovely.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The argument `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug` is available from iOS > 8 and OSX > 10.10 : make sure you target the right platform.

The console should log this if the flag is enabled :

`CoreData: annotation: Core Data multi-threading assertions enabled.`

Source : [Core Data Concurrency Debugging](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging/) from Ole Begemann

Comment: :-) Thanks for making an answer from your comments – I was going to ask if you'd mind if I did.

Comment: For iOS10/macOS 10.12, you will also need to specify "-com.apple.CoreData.Logging.stderr 1" to see the asserts in the debug console.  See section 'behavioral changes' in: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatNewCoreData2016/ReleaseNotes.html

Comment: Hi, where those who write articles learn it from? Debugging like this:     

 `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug` / `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` . I didn't find it in official Apple documentation.

Answer (score 21):

Working with XCode 8.x and iOS 10.x, I wanted to provide a streamlined answer for anyone wanting to implement this now.

You will first need to modify the scheme for your app:

[image]

Once you select Scheme, select Edit Scheme which should appear near the bottom of your list:
[image]

When opened, make sure that you have Run selected and choose Arguments.
You will want to copy the following values in:

- `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1`
- `-com.apple.CoreData.Logging.stderr 1`

Your screen should look like this:
[image]

After launching the app, you should see this appear in your console now when those options are enabled:

> CoreData: annotation: Core Data multi-threading assertions enabled.

And when you run into an exception generated by this, you will likely see this:

> CoreData`+[NSManagedObjectContext
>   **Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor**]:

You can return to the scheme editor and disable this logging as needed to prevent exceptions in the future.