# Possible CoreData crashing from users I can't reproduce

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

My application is hooked up with Crashlytics and around 9% of my users (close to 1k) are experiencing a crash I cannot replicate. In the specific line that is crashing, I am passing in my managed object context to a function that uses it to look up data.

Using dependency injection, I was able to instantiate my main view controller with the managed object context created in my AppDelegate. Any class that needs the managed object context gets it injected from this main view controller. Below is the stack trace I get in the Crashlytics dashboard. Any help is appreciated in helping me figure out what I can do.

```
    Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
    0  MyApp                      0x10008f47c specialized CalendarService.parseCalendarForMeetings(from : [EKEvent]?) -> [Meeting]? (CalendarService.swift:96)
    1  MyApp                      0x10006dbf4 specialized MeetingViewController.(launchCalendarService() -> ()).(closure #1) (MeetingViewController.swift:188)
    2  MyApp                      0x100071e64 partial apply for MeetingViewController.(launchCalendarService() -> ()).(closure #1) (MeetingViewController.swift)
    3  MyApp                      0x1000a5950 thunk (MeetingListMenuViewController.swift)
    4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1806fabb8 _dispatch_block_async_invoke_and_release + 100
    5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1806ee9a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1806f35e8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 996
    7  CoreFoundation                 0x1817e50c8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
    8  CoreFoundation                 0x1817e2ce4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1572
    9  CoreFoundation                 0x181712da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
    10 GraphicsServices               0x18317d074 GSEventRunModal + 100
    11 UIKit                          0x1879cdc9c UIApplicationMain + 208
    12 MyApp                          0x10005b3cc main (AppDelegate.swift:27)
    13 libdyld.dylib                  0x18072159c start + 4
```

EDIT:

This is the line of code (line 96 per the stack trace) that appears to be the problem. The MOC is not optional in the CalendarService class nor the CalendarUtility class.

Inside CalendarUtility, the MOC is used to read data only.

```
let calendarUtil = CalendarUtility(title: event.title, location: event.location, notes: event.notes, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
```

Comment: Add in the code that the top of the stack trace references and tell us what line is 96 in CalendarService.swift

Comment: Since you know the file and line number, the next thing you do is look at that code and see what could go wrong there, or in the code that leads to it. If you're not sure, update your question with that information. All anyone can really say based on this is that the app crashed at CalendarService.swift:96, which was called from MeetingViewController.swift:188.

Comment: Updated with the line of code causing the crash

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you are experiencing a race condition, and that the affected users tend to have faster or slower devices, which exposes the issue.

You can reference the following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391838/making-com-apple-coredata-concurrencydebug-1-work/43770903#43770903) which discusses adding a debug setting to check the thread that CoreData is using. If the actions are taking place on a background thread, then you are likely going to crash.

Comment: i added this and I'm seeing a core data violation crash. never knew of this debug flag before, so thanks for getting me in the right direction!

Comment: @iOShepherd Great to hear, CoreData can be a minefield at times, but that is a great asset to tame it.

Comment: So I tried to fix the code by using persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext() and got the crash so I switched back to my old code and inspected that, this time I did not get a crash... So my production code doesn't contain any violations :/