# Whats the CoreDat best practice to avoid crashes in a multi-threaded environment

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I followed few online tutorials and apples documentation in order to avoid crashes in my app. However its still crashing randomly and im unable to find the issue. Any help would much appreciate. Let me break-down the code in to two segments.

1. As apples does not recommend to use the appdelegate to access the persistant container in a multi-threaded environment,  I created a separate class to define my core-data stack, which is as follow.

   ```
   class CoreDataManager {

   static let sharedManager = CoreDataManager()

   private init() {} //Singleton


   lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

   let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyStore")

      container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (_, error) in

      if let error = error as NSError? {
       fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
      }
     })
   return container
   }()


   lazy var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
       return self.persistentContainer.viewContext
   }()


   lazy var updateContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
       let _updateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
       _updateContext.parent = self.viewContext
       return _updateContext
   }()

   }
   ```
2. As to access it I created another class that would give me the privilege of performing my operation as follow. I guess this is where the issue is.

   ```
   class StorageManager: NSObject {


   //Singleton SM class
    private override init() {}

    private static var SMInstance: StorageManager?

   //Globally accessible, shared instance of the class.
    public static var shared: StorageManager {
     if SMInstance == nil {
        SMInstance = StorageManager()
     }

     return SMInstance!
    }

    //Represent a single context for all the operations with lazy loading
    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {

      // CoreDataManager is from the core-data stack class created above
      return CoreDataManager.sharedManager.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }()

    lazy var privateMOC: NSManagedObjectContext = {

      return CoreDataManager.sharedManager.updateContext
    }()


   //This would manage my data saving 
    private func synchronize(privateMOC: NSManagedObjectContext) {
     do {
        try privateMOC.save() // We call save on the private context, which moves all of the changes into the main queue context without blocking the main queue.
        self.managedObjectContext.performAndWait {
            do {
               // print(Thread.current.threadName)
                try self.managedObjectContext.save()
               // print("Saved to main context")
            } catch {
                print("Could not synchonize data. \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

      } catch {
        print("Could not synchonize data. \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
    }
   ```

In the same class I have my DB operations, which is as follow.

```
  //Fetch saved data. Wherever use this, wrap it in a do catch block. Not sure if this method could cause the crash too.

   func fetchData<T: NSFetchRequestResult>(entity: String, model: T.Type, _ custom_predicate: NSPredicate?=nil) throws -> [T] {
   let request = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: entity)

     if custom_predicate != nil {
       request.predicate =   custom_predicate
     }

     request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

     return try privateMOC.fetch(request)

   }

   //support method to perform operations

   func deleteSpecialOffers(communityID:String)  {
    
    let privateMOC = self.privateMOC
        privateMOC.performAndWait {
               let request: NSFetchRequest<SpecialOffer> = SpecialOffer.fetchRequest()
               request.predicate =  NSPredicate(format: "community.community_id == %@", communityID)
               let result = try? privateMOC.fetch(request)

               for object in result ?? [] {
                   privateMOC.delete(object)
               }

               self.synchronize(privateMOC: privateMOC)

        }
     
    }
```

Comment: It would help if you could say which line(s) the crashes occur on.

Comment: i did mention its random

Comment: Then maybe you could add some examples.

Comment: Have you tried using ConcurrencyDebug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31426779 to track down the problem?